# Button size should be fixed even the text in it increases

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted the button size to be fixed in size, even though the text on the button increase.

The code I'm using now:

```css
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 1px 1px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button4 {
  background-color: #428BCA;
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.button4:hover {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button4">Simplfy!
  <br>Bona PARTe @ PT</button>
```

Comment: why are you doing height and width auto if you want the button size to be fixed?

Comment: then write width and height in px. but how can you achieve your target if you will keepsize fix and even you want size of textcan more.so you can achive one outof two either more text or fix size with less text

Answer (score 2):

add width, height to your button, and if you want to view overflow text write `overflow: auto`

```
.button4 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6L35bvL/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a fixed width and height for the button `height: 100px; width: 100px;` the auto won't work. The auto option will adapt to whatever object the button is in.

Comment: while doing above, the text disappers when I add more text

Comment: then increase the width of the button `height: 100px; width: 200px;`